# Differentiation Product Rule

Tags: derivatives

At the bottom of a proof I'm doing I end up with the following expression which equals zero.  But I can't see how?  I believe it has something to do with the product rule.

If someone can show me explicitly how it works out please.

Many thanks.

$$x\frac{d}{dy}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-y\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d^2}{dy^2}=0$$

Comment: You should really use MathJax and provide some context. As far as I am concerned, I have a hard time understanding your question.

Comment: Is there an equation relating $x,y$ somewhere in the proof, before getting to your equation (differential expression)=0?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that we are supposed to understand that the juxtaposition of two differential operators means their composition. Then, without other assumptions the claimed equality is false:
$$\left(x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\right)(x^2y)=2x.$$

Otherwise, if it is a product of differential operators, the claim is also false, one has:
$$\left(x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\right)(x^2y)=2x^3y.$$

So please post a new question in which you clarify the meaning of this juxtaposition of differential operators and provide us some context on the proof you are working on.